# Ionic Build Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: firebase, android-studio, ionic-framework

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > [string/google_app_id] /home/yushin/Desktop/b/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml   [string/google_app_id] /home/yushin/Desktop/b/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
  >   [string/google_api_key] /home/yushin/Desktop/b/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml  [string/google_api_key] /home/yushin/Desktop/b/TopStreetZambia/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Comment: In res folder inside platform > android there are some .xml file open in editor and please verify there are some keys are duplicate

Comment: Can you please explain more on what you mean? @PareshGami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it appear they was a duplication in google_app_id and google_app_key they belonged to two files one generated from google services, so what i did was went to android.json file and looked up

```
"res/values/strings.xml": {
    "parents": {
      "/resources": [
        {
          "xml": "<string name=\"google_app_id\">@string/google_app_id</string>",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "xml": "<string name=\"google_api_key\">@string/google_api_key</string>",
          "count": 1
        },
        ....
```

]

and removed

```
{
          "xml": "<string name=\"google_app_id\">@string/google_app_id</string>",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "xml": "<string name=\"google_api_key\">@string/google_api_key</string>",
          "count": 1
        }
```

that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: sir but in my android.json file both google_app_id and google_app_key  not visible in  my file tell me what i do now?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by just renaming `google_api_key` to `google_map_api_key`
just go to `strings.xml` and place the cursor at the `google_api_key` and press `shift+f6` to refactor it to the name you want

Comment: I just renamed my strings.xml with below :

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GalsKart</string>
    <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
    <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>
    <string name="google_api_key1">@string/google_api_key</string>
    <string name="google_app_id1">@string/google_app_id</string>
    <string name="google_map_api_key">@string/google_api_key</string>
</resources>